# If $|x -4 | + |y - 4| =4$ then how many integers value the sets (x,y) have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given

> If $|x -4| + |y - 4| =4$ then how many integers value the sets $(x,y)$ have?
>
> $x$ and $y$ are both positive and negative numbers.

options
a)infinite
b)$3$
c)$5$
d)$12$
e)$16$

Solution
My Approach:
i have just put all the values satisfying the equation
Hence,
Possible values are

$(0,4),(4,0)$

$ (2,6),(6,2)$

$ (1,3),(3,1)$

$ (3,7),(7,3)$

$ (5,7),(7,5)$

$ (8,0),(0,8)$

I am getting wrong ans as the Ans is $16$

Is there any better approach to this problem and why the my ans is wrong.

Comment: Check your calculations. $(1, 7)$ is not a solution

Comment: Hint: there are $2$ ways to make the LHS equal to $1,2, 3$ and for each, $2$ ways to make the RHS equal to $3, 2, 1$. Then consider the cases of $0, 4$ and $4, 0$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $|x-4|=0$ only if $x=4$ but there are two ways it can equal $1,2,3\text{ or }4$

Comment: Excellent hint. +1

Comment: @JalajChawla You need to count the number of ways of getting $0+4; 1+3; 2+2; 3+1; 4+0$  just be systematic about getting all the ways

Answer (score 2):

You have the right basic idea, but I think you would benefit from plotting the set out.  There are $16$ pairs:

$$
(4, 0), (4, 8) \\
(3, 1), (3, 7), (5, 1), (5, 7) \\
(2, 2), (2, 6), (6, 2), (6, 6) \\
(1, 3), (1, 5), (7, 3), (7, 5) \\
(0, 4), (8, 4)
$$

Alternatively, you can observe that the solutions can be characterized as $(4 \pm i, 4 \pm (4-i))$ for $0 \leq i \leq 4$, but note that there is only one value for $4 \pm 0$.

Comment: I like Mark Bennett s hint, but you have laid it out very clearly. +1

Comment: @Brian Tung How you generated these equation 4+- i,4+-(4-i)).This is good.

Comment: @JalajChawla: First of all, $i + (4-i) = 4$.  Since both addends are absolute values, they must be non-negative, so we restrict to $0 \leq i \leq 4$.  So $|x-4| = i$, therefore $x-4 = \pm i$, therefore $x = 4 \pm i$.  Similarly for $y$.

Comment: @Shailesh: I started out my answer not reading very carefully and thinking that Jalaj had gotten the right answer, but had just gotten some of the ordered pairs wrong.  Only after I was partway through writing down the pairs did I notice that the answer was wrong, too.  By that time, I didn't want to take out everything I had written and leave only the last paragraph as a hint, so I just added it in.

Comment: @BrianTung How |x-4|=i ?

Comment: @JalajChawla: It came from $i+(4-i) = 4$.  We identify $|x-4|$ with $i$, and $|y-4|$ with $4-i$.

Answer (score 0):

Best to work it backwards: Start with letting $x' = |x-4|$ and $y' = |y-4|$ . Now $x' + y' = 4$ and since absolute value only allows positive values then there are only 5 possibilities for $x'$ and $y'$: $(0,4), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (4,0)$. For any $x' \neq 0$, there are two values of $x$ that satisfy it, and similarly for $y'$ and $y$. For example, the solution corresponding to $(x',y') = (1,3)$ means that $x$ is either 3 or 5, and $y$ is either 1 or 7, thus $(x,y) \in \{(3,1),(3,7),(5,1),(5,7)\}$. From there you can enumerate backwards: if $(x',y') \in \{(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\}$, it's evident that you'll have 4 solutions for $(x,y)$. If either $x'=0$ or $y'=0$, then one of those two will only have a single solution, but the other will have two solutions. Therefore, you should have $2+4+4+4+2=16$ solutions total.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Above is a plot of the equation $|x-4|+|y-4|=4$. The 16 integer solutions are indicated as points.